# Joomla overrides my Quotes to &quote

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

I was trying to take advantage of the joomla class input by entering `scroll-link" data-id="home`

so the output would be: `<a class="scroll-link" data-id="home" href="#homes">Home</a>`

but instead joomla outputs: `<a class="scroll-link&quot; data-id=&quot;home" href="#homes">Home</a>`

Is there any way to turn off the conversion to &quot?

Comment: check your plugin manager search for tiny mce Basic options->prohibited text

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to do this is by overriding your menu module's output and adding the data-id attribute. Read more about layout overrides here - http://docs.joomla.org/Layout_Overrides_in_Joomla

What you're trying will not work since the class suffixes are most probably escaped to avoid incompatible characters.